# How to use two NXT bricks for 3+ motors and 4+ sensors?

Tags: nxt, mindstorms, bluetooth, nxc

I need to use multiple bricks in order to use more motors and sensors.  I need to read sensor values, and tell motors to move.

I've tried using bluetooth, however my attempts haven't been very successful.  I know you can pre-define motors/sensors, and then set parameters using remoteGetInputValues(), and the equivalent for motors.

Whilst playing around with this, I have noticed it doesn't work inside a loop, or inside it's own function?

Does anyone know of any tricks/hints/proper instructions on how to work it out?  I've tried looking everywhere for this.

The firmware is up to date, and I am programming in NXC.

Comment: You might want to checkout the question [How can I use more than three motors](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/646/56) which might solve your motor problem. Not sure if you can multiplex sensors though :(

Comment: Looking for the sensors!  I can gear up motors but how to get sensor values?! Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should look into using a multiplexer to add additional sensors to an NXT brick.

The [Hitechnic Sensor Multiplexer](http://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/hitechnic-sensor-multiplexer-lego-mindstorms.html) lets you connect 4 sensors using only 1 of the NXT connection.

[image]

The same thing can be done with motors. For example using the [Mindsensors NXTMMX](http://www.mindsensors.com/index.php?module=pagemaster&PAGE_user_op=view_page&PAGE_id=134), you can add 2 additional motors per multiplexer (even better, if you daisy-chain the multiplexers together you can control more motors than you'll ever need)

[image]