# Can I Conect 2 NXTs so that they work together?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, remote-control

I am building up a robot and I want to use 2 NXT connected together because I need more than 3 ports A,B,C. So my question here is: When I write the code, is there anything different I have to do?

For example do I write the same code I would use for 2 NXT and just connect them together or do I have to do something more than this?

I found a way to connect them but I have not found examples yet of the blocks (nxt code software).

Comment: You might also find [How can I use more than 3 motors with one NXT brick](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/646/56) useful :)

Answer (score 2):

Without 3rd party hardware or software, the only way to do this is to use Bluetooth messages. For example, you could write motor power to a Bluetooth mailbox on one NXT. The other NXT just has a simple program with a loop that reads the Bluetooth mailbox and connects it to a motor block.