# Is it possible to use 5 motors on an EV3 brick?

Tags: ev3, programming, motor

The EV3 brick has only four output ports (A B C & D) to run motors. Is there any way to use port 1 (sensor port) to control a motor?

Answer (score 8):

A sensor port can't directly output to a motor. The sensor drivers can't provide enough power to supply a motor.
You have a couple options:

- Daisy-chain two EV3s together. The first can control the sensors and
  motors of the second.
- Use an electronic [motor multiplexer](http://www.mindsensors.com/ev3-and-nxt/21-multiplexer-for-nxtev3-motors). EDIT: It should be noted that this requires an external power supply, which will increase the cost and complexity of your project.
- Depending on your project, you might be able to make do with only 4 motors. See this response for [driving multiple outputs with a single motor](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/646/how-can-i-use-more-than-three-motors-with-one-nxt-brick/650#650).

Comment: It depends on what you are making, but if you are very creative you can do many, many things with just one motor such as with [this railway system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_302Wfpai3w). Each rail cart has a motor that provides drive for a hopper and conveyor in addition to the drive of the cart.